# Update primary SQL Server in mirrored environment using transaction logs from old environment

Tags: sql-server, migration, mirroring

I'm currently migrating a large (~40gb) database to a new environment. The new environment is a HA/mirrored set up with primary, mirror and witness nodes.

I'm backing up the database in the old environment, restoring to primary & mirror, and turning on mirroring. During this time the old environment is still active, and data is changing. When we are ready to go live with the new environment I plan to take another transaction log from the *old* environment and restore that to the new primary server. Is that possible? Will this be successfully synchronised to the mirror?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now believe the approach I am looking for is

- Restore backup from A to B Primary and B Mirror
- Wait for migration time
- Take a transaction log from A
- Restore transaction log on B Primary
- Restore transaction log on B Mirror with NORECOVERY
- Set reconnect mirroring

Answer (score 0):

> *When we are ready to go live with the new environment I plan to take another transaction log from the old environment and restore that to the new primary server. Is that possible? Will this be successfully synchronized to the mirror?*

You can set up mirroring as normal. But when you want to failover, then use SYNCHRONOUS - High safety without automatic failover.

[image]

using T-SQL :

```
ALTER DATABASE <<DB NAME>> SET PARTNER FAILOVER
```

Doing so, only the role reversal happens and mirroring direction is reversed - principal becomes mirror and vice-versa. Note that MIRRORING is not BROKEN.

Now once you verify everything is OK, then you can break mirroring with below steps :

**Turn mirroring off** (break mirroring) on the mirror DB.

```
ALTER DATABASE <<DB NAME>> SET PARTNER OFF
```

Set the DB to RECOVERY

```
RESTORE DATABASE <<DB NAME>> WITH RECOVERY
```

Migrate Logins as well as any sql agent jobs to secondary. You might have to fix orphaned users.

```
EXEC sp_change_users_login ‘Auto_Fix’ , ‘<<username>>’
```

Comment: Hi Kin really sorry but I'm not looking to failover... I've actually got environment A and environment B, looking to move the DB from environment A to environment B while environment A is still running, then at the last minute do another update from A->B and go live with B.

Comment: @Aligma If I understand your question, you want to failover your old mirrored DB to new server. Then just change the mirroring mode to use SYNCHRONOUS - High safety without automatic failover. And then initiate a failover. Your secondary will become primary. Refer to **Database availability during planned downtime** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917681.aspx#EIAA

Comment: the database in the old environment is not mirrored, and the database servers are in two different networks.

Comment: @Aligma please specify that in your question so we can help you by giving correct answer. why do you want mirroring ? Have you looked into logshipping as that will be more easy to setup and when you want to failover, you just have to take a tail log backup from primary and then apply it to secondary server with recovery to bring the secondary database online.

Comment: the database in the old environment is not mirrored, the new mirrored database is running across new servers in a new network